# DB2 CLOB and different encodings

Tags: sql, db2

Is it possible to save data in CLOB column in DB2 with different encodings in the same table, for example:

```
create table mytable (
    mytext CLOB
);
```

- first row - mytext field with UTF-8 text
- second row - mytext field with windows-1251 text

Comment: Curious to know why you would want to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course save data with different encoding, but DB2 will treat them as if they all were in the same database-level (or column-level, depending on your DB2 version and platform) encoding, so results will be unpredictable.

If you don't want the database to mess with encoding of your textual data you should use the BLOB data type instead.